# Detecting Drag and Drop and detecting long press (XNA or as3)

Tags: input, xna, touch, mouse, drag

i am trying to implement a drag and drop behaviour for an object, i need to register when the touch is being pressed and after moving it a bit it should start dragging.

unfortunately i am using a custom framework that is implemented in C# and it's something like XNA.

How would you do it on XNA?

(it's for an android tablet) .

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this example should be refactored to use input services and better handling for the touch up/down concepts, but the core of the answer remains the same:

```
// I don't remember the exact property names, but you probably understand what I mean
public override void Update(GameTime time) 
{
    var currentState = TouchPanel.GetState();
    var gestures = currentState.TouchGestures;
    var oldGests = this.oldState.TouchGestures;

    if (oldGests.Count == 0 && gestures.Count == 1 && gestures[0].State == Pressed)
    {
        // Went from Released to Pressed
        this.touchPressed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Not the frame it went to Pressed
        this.touchPressed = false;
    }

    if (oldGests.Count == 1 && gestures.Count == 1 && oldGests[0].State == Pressed && gestures[0].State == Pressed)
    {
        // Touch is down, and has for more than 1 frame (aka. the user is dragging)
        this.touchDown = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.touchDown = false;
    }


    if (oldGests.Count == 1 && oldGests[0].State == Pressed && gestures.Count == 0)
    {
        // Went from Released to Pressed
        this.touchReleased = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Not the frame it went to Pressed
        this.touchReleased = false;
    }

    this.oldState = currentState;
}
```

You might have to fiddle with the 'ifs' a bit, since I don't actually remember if Gestures goes down to 0 the first frame after you release your finger, or if it still shows 1 Gesture called 'Released'. Test it, and you shall have your answer!

Now you can use 'this.touchDown' elsewhere in your code to determine if your object should move or not.